# Orange Canvas 3.3.6 - "MemoryError" while running k-means clustering widget

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, orange

I am having trouble running a k-means clustering widget in Orange 3.3.6. I am trying to run it on a data set with 46k rows but I keep getting a memory error and the widget crashes. If I trim it down to 12030 rows it will run. Obviously I want it to run on the entire dataset.

I have tried installing the newest version of orange, trimming out every redundant column in my data file except for the few that I really need, normalising my data and setting it to 5 decimal places.

I am running windows 8.1 pro 64 bit, and have 8gb of ram. I really feel like Orange should be able to cope with more data than this.

I ran the same 46k row dataset through a k-means clusting algorithm in the software ioGas(by reflex) and it ran through fine in a just a few seconds.

Is there anything I can try to get Orange to perform better?

This is the error message that the Orange Canvas GUI throws out.

```
MemoryError                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\widgets\gui.py", line 2228, in <lambda>
    b.button = btn = button(b, master, label, callback=lambda: do_commit())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\widgets\gui.py", line 2199, in do_commit
    commit()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\widgets\unsupervised\owkmeans.py", line 250, in run
    self.cluster()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\widgets\unsupervised\owkmeans.py", line 239, in cluster
    max_iter=self.max_iterations)(self.data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\projection\base.py", line 28, in __call__
    clf = self.fit(data.X, data.Y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\clustering\kmeans.py", line 25, in fit
    proj.silhouette = silhouette_score(X, proj.labels_)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\unsupervised.py", line 95, in silhouette_score
    return np.mean(silhouette_samples(X, labels, metric=metric, **kwds))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\unsupervised.py", line 158, in silhouette_samples
    distances = pairwise_distances(X, metric=metric, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 1207, in pairwise_distances
    return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 1054, in _parallel_pairwise
    return func(X, Y, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 231, in euclidean_distances
    distances = safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 184, in safe_sparse_dot
    return fast_dot(a, b)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 1):

Not k-means is the problem, but Silhouette.

Silhouette computes pairwise distances, and thus needs O(n^2) memory. So you are simply running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try running 64-bit Python. I suggest [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which comes with 64-bit Python and then you can simply:

```
conda install -c anaconda orange3=3.3.6
```